# DeepSpeech: Distinguish speakers

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

I try to use DeepSpeech for call center, to dictate and summary conversation.

In this scenario, there are always more than one speaker, usually two speakers.  Is there any way to distinguish the speakers while DeepSpeech is recognizing the conversation?

Thanks for your advice.
Jin.